# How to emulate keyboard event 'Enter' key

Tags: javascript, casperjs

My current scenario is, Enter some text in ace content/ command prompt and hit the 'Enter' key, which will create a cell. 
and below is the code which i am executing but it is not working

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys(".ace_content", "a<-12; print a");
    this.sendKeys(".ace_content", {keepFocus: true});
    this.capture("test37_2.png");
    this.page.sendEvent("keypress", casper.page.event.key.Enter);
    this.capture("test37_3.png");
 });

casper.wait(3000);

casper.then(function(){
    this.test.assertExists({type:'xpath', path:".//*[@id='part1.R']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/pre/code"});
});
```

Comment: Maybe add a `this.wait(1000, function(){ ... })` around `sendEvent` and the subsequent `capture`? There is really not enough to help you here, because the script looks fine. Can you provide a complete running script with the site?

Comment: i can give you the script but the problem is you need to setup the RCloud on your local machine to access the site.

Comment: You're right. I'm not going to do that. The only other "fix" would be to try another version of PhantomJS (1.9.8 vs. 2.0). Maybe you could try it with the SlimerJS engine.

Comment: as you said, added this.wait() aroound the sendEvent but it is not triggering the Enter key. Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: i even tried this code but still, `casper.evaluate(function triggerKeyDownEvent() {
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
jQuery(".ace_content").trigger(e);
}); 
`